# Get orders books for markets on binance

Tags: python, api

How I can get all BTC and ETH orders books with binance API? Now I use python for it

```
pairs = ["TRXETH", "TRXBTC"]
for pair in pairs:
    # get market depth
    depth = client.get_order_book(symbol=pair)
```

but this way doesn't work if I need to get all 200 symbol orders books from binance because it takes about 5 minutes to get it and I think server can block my API for spam requests. Is it possible to do it more quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm having trouble myself using the Rest API to set the limit of depth in the get_order_book call you are using. But I'm able to retrieve real time information from the orderbook with Binance's Websockets, you could define a websocket for each symbol and then start the socket and have the callback function figure out what to do with the returned information.

Something like this:

```
    # Callback function
    def depth_message(msg):
        print ("Symbol: ", msg['s'])
        if msg['b']:
            print ("Buy: ", msg['b'])
        if msg['a']:
            print ("Sell: ", msg['a'])`


    # Creating the websocket and starting it.
    bm = websockets.BinanceSocketManager(client)
    time.sleep(3)
    bm.start_depth_socket('BTCUSDT', depth_message)
    bm.start_depth_socket('ETHUSDT', depth_message)
    .
    .
    .
    bm.start_depth_socket('TRXBTC', depth_message)
    bm.start()
```

The output, with the callback function I exemplified should look something like this:
`

```
Symbol:  BTCUSDT
Buy:  [['7480.00000000', '0.37765500', []]]
Sell:  [['7480.63000000', '0.01329200', []]]
Symbol:  ETHUSDT
Buy:  [['591.53000000', '0.27000000', []], ['591.50000000', '0.06706000', []], ['589.90000000', '7.81833000', []], ['587.86000000', '0.39787000', []]]
Sell:  [['593.80000000', '0.66726000', []]
```

Once you execute this example you should see a constant output like the above one being displayed in your console until you stop the program, you don't need a loop as the socket updates constantly for each of the symbols you define a socket for. You could use a loop to set all the websocket calls you want for each symbol.

You can read more about Binance Websockets [here](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md) and I'm using [this](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance) Binance Python API in my example.

Hope this helps!